# An application of the multidimensional version of Itô's formula

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am starting to study the multidimensional version of Ito's lemma .
The book shows an exercise that I don't understand.
The exercise is:

$(X_t^1,X_t^2)$ is a 2-dimensional Brownian motion and $F(t,x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$.

Reviewing the theory well:

Two-dimensional case:  $d(_t\int_{0}^{t}s \space dW_s) =$ ?

$X_t^1 = W_t$ and $X_t^2 = \int_{0}^{t}s \space dW_s\\$

I calculated the partial derivatives: $F(t,x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$ ,

$\partial {x_1}F = x_2$

$\partial {x_2}F = x_1$

$\partial _{x_1x_1}F = \partial _{x_2x_2}F= 0$.

$\partial {x_1}{x_2}F = 1$

I pose: $dX_t^1 = dW_t\space \space$ and $dX_t^2 = t dW_t$

Apply Ito:

$dF(X_t^1,X^2_t)= X_t^1dX_t^2 + X_t^2dX_t^1 + \frac{1}{2}2d\langle X_t^1,X_t^2\rangle$

hence the result posted above $d(X_{t}^1X_{t}^2) = X_{t}^1 dX_{t}^2 + X_{t}^2 dX_{t}^1+ \beta dt$.

It's correct? Thanks.

Comment: "The book" : which book ?

Comment: I cannot say the author, but it is an Italian book on stochastic calculus for finance. It seems to me that several steps are missing to be able to understand the resolution well. Thanks.

Comment: What terms do you get when you apply the Ito formula to $f(t,X_t,Y_t)$ where $f(t,x,y)=xy$ ?

Comment: Hi Kurt, I looked at the theory well and re-edited the text.  
maybe I'm starting to understand. Thanks.

Comment: The derivatives of $F$ look OK. The processes $X,Y,X^1,X^2,W,B^1,B^2$ and what not are a total mess. Recommendation : just use two BM $B^1$ and $B^2$ and get rid of all others.

Comment: I would say better. I rewrote the exercise with more accurate terminology. Thanks.

Comment: Once again, please review this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some advice on proper formatting. As it stands, your post is quite difficult to read.

Comment: Your question after I edited it is still unclear ... what is the result you want to prove please state it unambiguously